# Math: Solve for X in PHP

Tags: php, math

Trying to create a function solve for X in PHP for the following example though I'm not sure where to start.
(52 + x) / 3 = 73

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Give it a shot. Can't learn if you don't try.

Comment: Start with the lecture notes.

Comment: start with Math by reverting the expression to get an equation like x = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for special function. Try this (73 * 3) - 52 = 167.